# How can I open the front of my dryer?

Tags: repair, dryer

[Here is a site with exploded diagrams of the unit.](http://www.appliancepartspros.com/partsearch/model.aspx?model_id=246223&diagram_id=28133606#d28133606) If I need to oil the main bearing on the on the drum or one of the roller guide wheels of the drum, do I need to undo the back assembly, or can I access it from the front somehow?

I am worried about any disassembly involving undoing the seals (as I don't  want to disturb them if they are still working), but if it would be possible to go through the front it might be simpler.

Comment: Follow up: it turns out the only way through to the rollers was lifting the top and taking off the front panel due to no access on back and the sides and bottom were one piece of sheet metal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the hassle of pulling the unit out, I would say back, bottom, or top access is better. Front access is possible, but the whole shell (outer box) of the dryer is built around the front, side and top panels connecting together, and in the end taking the front panel completely off is going to be more hassle than it is worth. Usually a smaller bottom portion of the front panel comes off, and if that gives you the access you need then that is an easy place to start. Otherwise, again, go from the back, or bottom, or even from the top. On my dryer, the top swings up on a hing at the back, swinging up the whole top section and control panel. Look to see if yours similarly has a hinge at the back, about 6 inches down from the top back edge of the control panel. If so, that tells you the top does swing up. The trick is there are no screws holding it, it is held by metal clips. You use a metal putty knife or screwdriver inserted in the crack between the top and the front, at the right and left corners on the front. Push the putty knife in until it stops, then bump it in further with the heel of your hand to depress a clip mechanism that will free that corner. Do likewise on the other corner, and then the top should swing up on the back hinge.
Hope this helps.